# ps3 controller not syncing

Tags: ps3

I have a ps3 controller dual axis that keeps flashing and wont connect to my ps3. It was given to me and I was told that it hadn't been working.I put batteries from one control which I had into it but all it does is flashes. Tried all methods of resetting but it wont work. Even when I connect it using the cable it wont flash/turn on. It only flashes when I press the ps button and then turns off after about a minute . Anyone has any ideas. Need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple tips/advice here:

- Perhaps try changing the cable, the cable may be faulty and not allow
  the controller to sync.
- The flashing lights may mean it needs to charge. Just leave it cabled in for a while, and then press the PS button to sync it.
- If neither of these work, if you turn the PS3 controller over, to the (now) left of the L2 trigger is a smallish hole. If you get a toothpick you can press that down to reset the controller, which may allow it to connect. It will not re-sync without the cable.